# Authentication Manager error in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

Am trying to develop spring secure Application with Spring 2.5 version.Am getting error in security config file.

here is my authentication manager declaration:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider >
    <user-service>
      <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Am facing following error:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'authentication-manager' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty..

this my security.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd">
<http auto-config="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider >
<user-service>
<user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Could you please post your security xml file?

Comment: Hi I have posted security xml file also.please let me know if you have any soluton.

Comment: I am not sure that this kind of syntax (`authentication-provider` as a child of `authentication-manager`) is available for your Spring Security version. Can you switch to Spring Security 3.1?